# How to avoid passing of map as reference in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using ML 8.0-8

Is there any way to not to pass Map to a function as a reference.

I mean if I make any update in a map in the function it should not reflect in the actual map.

Example:

```
function call($map as map:map) {
     'add one more key in the $map'
}

declare $actualMap
call($actualMap)
print $actualMap
```

Updates in the call function should not reflect in the $actualMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll basically have to clone it. You can do that with a one-liner in XQuery, by serializing and parsing it:

```
let $clonedMap := map:map(document{ $map }/*)
```

Note though that a `map:map` could hold items that cannot be serialized, like function references. In that case, you need to reconstruct the `map:map`. For instance with:

```
let $clonedMap := map:new(map:keys($map) ! map:entry(., map:get($map, .)))
```

The second method might actually be faster, but it doesn't process a map:map recursively, while the first method would. You could wrap the second in a recursive function with a typeswitch to compensate.

HTH!